# How to inflate a layout in method in fragment

Tags: java, android

actually I have a fragment.`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View promptView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);

    sendRestoreRequest2();

    return promptView;
}


public void sendRestoreRequest2() {

     final TextView df=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.df);//this will give an error. I dont know how to inflate this one because this is a fragment.
    }
```

How to fix this? Because in activity we can just  final TextView df=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.df) in method and it will work.

Comment: show the logcat of error ?

Comment: `sendRestoreRequest2(promptView);

    return promptView;
}


public void sendRestoreRequest2( View promptView ) {

     final TextView df=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.df);//this will give an error. I dont know how to inflate this one because this is a fragment.
    }`

Comment: @SushilKumar Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: check the df id in your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone I am a newbie in fragment.I just discovered the solution

Put this inoncreateview.
  Change from final TextView df=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.df); to 
     df = view.findViewById(R.id.df);

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

YOU are **not having the scope of the inflated PromptView** in the method which is out side of the ONCREATEVIEW's scope

> one thing that you can do is like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View promptView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);

    sendRestoreRequest2(promptView);

    return promptView;
}


public void sendRestoreRequest2(View incomingPromptView) {
     // here now you have that promptView in your other method's scope and this should register the TextView in your Fragment
     final TextView df=(TextView)incomingPromptView.findViewById(R.id.df);
    }
```

> Solution number Two is like this

You can do findViewbyid in a fragment class by the useage of simple getActivty().findViewbyId by overRiding the method of OnActivityCreated in your Fragment class (but it is a passive approach though)

Answer (score 0):

**You have to create a global `View promptView` variable in your fragment.**

Your code should look something like this:

```
private View promptView = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(promptView == null){
       promptView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);

       sendRestoreRequest2();
    }
    return promptView;
}


public void sendRestoreRequest2() {
    final TextView df=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.df);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View promptView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
   sendRestoreRequest2(promptView);
   return promptView;
}

public void sendRestoreRequest2(View promptView) {
   final TextView df = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.df);
}
```